# Dados da sessão em php

Tags: php

Estou usando um certificado SSL, e queria saber se é possível que o usuário vejas os dados salvos na sessão?

Exemplo, tenho uma variável chamada config, onde guardo algumas configurações de acesso do usuário. Ele consegue alterar esses dade de alguma forma? Com cookie da para fazer isso pelo próprio browser.

Queria saber se isso e possível com sessão pois os dados ficam no servidor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os dados da sessão ficam no servidor, sem acesso direto por um terceiro não autorizado.

Uma possibilidade de obter acesso a uma determinada sessão é o sequestro de sessões, conhecido em inglês como "session hijacking".

Uma sessão necessita de um ID. Esse ID é salvo num cookie pelo browser do usuário. Um outro usuário malicioso, em posse do computador da vítima, pode simplesmente copiar esse cookie para outra máquina e assim terá o acesso a sessão aberta pela vítima. Ou seja, isso é um sequestro de sessão.

Consulte pela busca do site: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=sequestro+sess%C3%A3o

Outro modo de literalmente roubar as sessões é um invasor conseguir acesso ao servidor. Um invasor experiente vai direto em locais óbvios onde pode conseguir dados valiosos. Um desses locais é a pasta onde as sessões são salvas. Muitos programadores salvam dados sensíveis sem criptografia, ficando em texto puro. Aí é mamão com açúcar para um hacker pegar senhas de centenas ou milhares de usuários.
Em casos mais toscos há aqueles que salvam até dados de cartão de crédito. Acredite se quiser, esse absurdo acontece.

obs: O SSL não aumenta a segurança, é indiferente para esse caso.

Comment: "O SSL não aumenta a segurança, é indiferente para esse caso" exatamente. Pra este caso, o SSL não tem nada a ver. O SSL só aumenta segurança em caso de interceptação dos dados.

Comment: Existe alguma forma de melhorar a segurança contra o roubo de dados?

Comment: clique no link presente na resposta....